# How to declare `async` functional component in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to load the image in typescript. but not works. what is the correct way?

Here is my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { FC } from "react";

type ImageLoad = (subString: string) => Promise<boolean>;

const App: FC = async () => {
  const imgsource: ImageLoad = await import("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <img src={imgsource} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit brave-sutherland-fcigc]

Comment: Why do you need to dynamic import that image then?

Comment: You can't. Function-based components need to return an element, not a promise of one. You'd have to use e.g. `useEffect` and re-render once the image is imported.

Comment: Components can't be `async`.  But within components you can manage state and after an `async` operation update that state.

Comment: so, how to import the image and assign it then?

Comment: Async rendering is not yet available in React. You'll need to use the [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for any async tasks.

Comment: @jsejcksn - here is my try : https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sutherland-fcigc?file=/src/App.tsx can you help me?

Comment: Why are you trying to "import" an image instead of just setting that URL to the `src` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

No async code is needed in your example. Because you already have the URL of the image, all you need to do is set the image's `src` attribute:

```tsx
const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: it's ok. But for my case i need to switch the image by conditional. so it like slide show. i like to keep all url in array. accordingly to load when needs